# PythonAnywhere и асинхронность

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, асинхронность, pythonanywhere

Как в pythonanywhere на django написать асинхронную функцию? К примеру пользователь что-то нажал, и это активирует асинхронную функцию, которая к примеру обработает введённые данные асинхронно, чтобы не прерывать работу основного скрипта.

Comment: как вариант - использовать celery. пишите таску и запускаете её my_task.delay()

Comment: сельдерей лишний для небольших проектов. просто в тред

Comment: threading? Так в pythonanywhere проект запускается через reload, и чтобы запустили thread'ы нужно релоаднуть, в этом-то и проблема.

Comment: как в тред, это я и спрашиваю

Comment: pythonanywhere просто не поддерживает много видов асинхронности